# Django- user foreign key

Tags: django

I have been doing a project where I added user (custom user model) as a foreign key(field name, added_by) to another model(say, post). Now I want to filter from post table by a specific user and/or logged in user. How do I do that? 
I tried the following,

```
content= post.object.filter(added_by=request.user.username)
```

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of the model you aim to filter.

Comment: If you did it properly, then the logged in user is stored in `request.user`.

Comment: Please find the edited text above, I tried to filter by logged in user. It returns integer value error.

Comment: It is `post.objects.filter(added_by=request.user)`.

Comment: haha... thanks ! it was pretty easy. Worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you implemented the [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms) properly, `request.user` will contain a reference to a custom user model object for the user that is logged in.

You can filter on a `ForeignKey` by passing a reference to the object, so here we can implement this as:

```
Post.objects.filter(added_by=request.user)
```